# Store a table column name as variable in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a sql server stored procedure where I want the table column name to be stored as variable.But I am finding it difficult.

**CODE**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLeaveDays] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @LeaveType varchar,@AdminId int
 AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT @LeaveType  FROM CompulsoryLeave WHERE AdminId =@AdminId
END
```

Where the @Leavetype is the name of the table column.

**EDIT**
This is how I execute the stored procedure

```
GetLeaveDays 'Maternity',1
```

Comment: dynamic TSQL...........similar questions asked many times

Comment: @MitchWheat can you add a link to a previous question?

Comment: how about you do a search?.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL as suggested. In your case you could use the following T-SQL.
You can read docs for dynamic SQL at [Dynamic SQL in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

Keep in mind to always use  `sp_executesql` to execute your dynamically formed queries since it's more secure that using `EXEC (@query)`.

```
DECLARE @queryString nvarchar(MAX);


SET @queryString = 'SELECT ' + @LeaveType + ' WHERE AdminId = @AdminId';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @queryString,
        N'@AdminId int',
         @AdminId = @AdminId;
```

Using the above approach, your stored procedure would now look like the following.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLeaveDays] -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @LeaveType varchar(5000), 
  @AdminId int 
 AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @queryString nvarchar(MAX);


SET @queryString = 'SELECT ' + @LeaveType + 'FROM CompulsoryLeave WHERE AdminId = @AdminId';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @queryString,
        N'@AdminId int',
         @AdminId = @AdminId;

END
```

Comment: when I input the column name I get invalid column N

Comment: What did you input for column name?

Comment: Try the stored procedure now since I have made a small change to it.  The `@LeaveType `  parameter  was defined as  `varchar`,  when it should have been defined with its max length like `varchar(5000)`.

Comment: you saved my day. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sp_executesql` command for this purpose. You can read this [Article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/) to get a nice review on dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(max);
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @LeaveType + ' FROM CompulsoryLeave WHERE AdminId = '''+@AdminId+''''
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@AdminId int', @AdminId = @AdminId;
```

Comment: when I input the column name I get invalid column N

Comment: Can you share please table CompulsoryLeave and what is the parameter r you giving while execute the procedure?

Comment: GetLeaveDays 'Maternity',1. Getleavedays is the name of the stored procedure Maternity my first parameter and 1 my second parameter

Comment: I just posted it

Comment: sorry pretty mistake last line of my submitted answer. I have edited my answer. can you please try my updated SQL please?

Comment: I just tried and I got the error:Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetLeaveDays, Line 9
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT A FROM CompulsoryLeave WHERE AdminId = '' to data type int.